# How can we deploy a BizTalk solution from BizTalk Deployment Framework using command prompt

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-deployment, btdf

I have a biztalk solution and configuration file (.btdfproj) included in the solution, using which the deployment is done. The solution have multiple projects and all are deployed using the same configuration file mentioned above.
I also publish a service (svc) to IIS and this is also configured in the same file.
I want to perform all these using command line.

Answer (score 1):

The Deployment Framework documentation [discusses scripted deployments](http://www.tfabraham.com/btdfdocs/v5_0/DeployinganApplicationviaScript.html).  You can also take a look at [Randy Paulo's PowerShell script](http://randypaulo.wordpress.com/2012/01/31/automating-silent-install-biztalk-deployment-framework-btdf-using-powershell/).